# QT: ui_* files not generated

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, makefile, qmake

I know it is a topic already touched by a lot of user, but I don't find a valid solution; I have two form files created with QtDesigner:

interfaccia_test.ui
interfaccia.ui

I launch `qmake -project` command obtaing the following `.pro` file:

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = qtgeo
INCLUDEPATH += . include

# Input
HEADERS += interfaccia.h include/localizzazione.hpp
FORMS += interfaccia.ui interfaccia_test.ui
SOURCES += interfaccia.cpp main.cpp src/localizzazione.cpp
src/SimpleSIFT.cpp
```

so i give `qmake` command but it doesn't generate `ui_interfaccia.h` and `ui_interfaccia_test.h` like I expected; then I try to `make` my project and I have

```
interfaccia.h:19:28: fatal error: ui_interfaccia.h: File o directory not found
#include "ui_interfaccia.h"
                        ^
```

with `interfaccia.h` my file that use the GUI I made.

Answer (score 3):

For any given project, you should ever only use `qmake -project` *once*. It's meant as a starting point if you have a bunch of files and want to get a project *template*. This template is then meant to be modified by a human being - you.

The normal way to build a qmake-based Qt project would be:

```
qmake
make
```

The `ui_xxx.h` files are generated by `make`, not `qmake`. Here's a list of what the various tools do:

- `qmake -project` Generates a `.pro` file template for you to modify to suit the project. This should never be used by your end users, or by you after the project is going. It's your job to keep the `.pro` file up-to-date.
- `qmake` or `cmake` Generates the makefile for the build system.
- `make` or `ninja` Builds the project, generating all the other files.

There are two additional points:

1. The qmake won't generate the `ui_xxx.h` file if you've included a file that wouldn't be generated. So, for example, if it'd generate a file called `ui_Interfaccia.h`, but you've included `ui_interfaccia.h`, then the file with the wrong name *nor* the file with the correct name get generated.

   This matters even if you're building everything on a case-insensitive OS/filesystem.
2. You're including the file with a wrong name. The correct name is `ui_ClassName.h`, where `ClassName` is the name of the class from the .ui file (look at the first few lines), with the same capitalization.

Comment: I'm talking about the build folder. You really should do shadow builds outside of the source folder.

Comment: done. I create a directory build, go inside it and do `qmake ..`; it generates Makefile, I type `make` but with same results..fatal error: ui_interfaccia.h not found (no such file ecc)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78543/discussion-between-volperossa-and-kuba-ober).

Comment: @KubaOber: Hello, I have a question on the class defined in the generated ui header file. Is the name of the class the same as the objectName of the background of the ui form?

Comment: @jingweimo Yes, it is. IIRC, the `objectName` is rewritten to make it a valid C++ identifier.